# MySQL/MariaDB - Reset password without DB restart

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

unfortunately I forgot to note down the new password from the last recovery. This means I can't login as root and the init script can't restart it due to not having been updated (sys_maint).

Is there a way for me to fix this, most of the guides I found require you to restart the mysql server, well, doesn't work in my case.

I could kill the process but am I able to start it up again afterwards?
If so I could probably use this way, if it works with mariadb:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix

Comment: Sorry, no.  How insecure would you like MySQL to be?  Now give yourself another `SUPER` user (`WITH GRANT OPTION`) so that you will have an extra way in (via `localhost` only).

Comment: If you are still logged in as root, change the password and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few more hours with the issue I tried the one way and it even worked, though I didn't have any access to the database. So in terms of security concerns, well its even official..:
**B.5.4.1.2** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html